# How to get Registered event of control in vb6

Tags: vb6

Basically I am trying to get all the events registered to the control i.e. Button, ComboBox. and event can be anything like OnFocus, OnClick etc and call those events

SO, I need some getEvent type thing..that returns events of a given control

Is there any possible way??

//Suppose There is button B

//and registered event is

```
B_click(){
// whatever
}
```

//so is there any way to get like

```
B.getRegisterdEvents()
```

// and that return B_click???

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you, but I have a question: Why?

Comment: i need to create a virtual keyboard for an system that requires me to call its events on every keypress--so...I need event names to call them, when a event accurs on virtual keyboard of mine

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish. A control can have multiple events so you need to have some idea what event you want to call. But I believe at least part of your answer is to use the `CallByName` function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262682(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: yup callByName does call a fucntion but i have to name the function which I have to call...How to get the name of the Function is what I am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a list of all the operations that are part of an object's interface, all you have to do is open the Object Browser (View/Object Browser or F2).  Click on the object you're looking for (e.g. a CommandButton object), and you'll see a list of all the events, methods and  properties it supports.

If you need to do it programmatically, it's not difficult either.  First, set a reference to "TypeLib Information".  This example prints all attributes and operations for a command button called Command1 to the Debug window:

```
Dim ta As TLIApplication
Dim ti As TypeInfo
Dim mi As MemberInfo

Set ta = New TLIApplication
Set ti = ta.InterfaceInfoFromObject(Command1)

For Each mi In ti.Members
    Debug.Print mi.Name
Next
```

If you want to dig deeper, [this CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5180/RunTime-COM-Object-Inspection) should help.